# Table made of <DIV> is very slow

Tags: php, css

I decided to write my own markup for a table that has a static header and scrollable tbody (using Jquery), so i decided to write my own markup using divs.

Here are the 2 problems :

- given any query to select x rows, it prints a resultset on two rows, so a counting error might have occured
- this markup is very slow when we're talking about huge ammounts of data, lots of DOM elements, when using some static markup, it's ok, but when I'm supposed to fetch it from a DB, it's lagging a lot

I was wondering if you guys might have an idea, days of searching have failed me

The code is below :

```
<?php include("connect.inc.php"); ?>

<html>

<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $(".thead").scroll(function () { 
                $(".tbody").scrollLeft($(".thead").scrollLeft());
            });
        $(".tbody").scroll(function () { 
                $(".thead").scrollLeft($(".tbody").scrollLeft());
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

<?php

    /* $syntax = ANY USUAL MYSQL SELECT QUERY, EVEN A JOIN */

    $query  = mysql_query($syntax) or die(mysql_error());
    $cols   = mysql_num_fields($query)+1;
    $td_w   = 150;  $tr_w = $cols*$td_w;    /* td_width default 150px :) */

?>

<style type="text/css">

*   {

    font-size:12px;
    font-family:verdana;

}

/* defines table wrap, max width and height */

.tbl_wrap   {

    width:800px;
    height:400px;

}

/* inner wrapper */

.tbl    {

    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}

.thead {

    height:35px;
    overflow:hidden;

}

.tbody {

    height:400px;
    overflow:auto;

}

/* defines table row and table header settings */

.th,.tr {

    width:<?=$tr_w."px"?>;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    height:35px;

}

/* optional settings for th */

.th {

    background-color: rgb(220,220,220);
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;

}

/* cell element styling */

.td {

    float:left; 
    display:inline;
    width:<?=$td_w."px"?>;
    height:35px;
    overflow:auto;
    border: 1px solid rgb(250,250,250);

}

</style>    

<div class='tbl_wrap'>

    <div class='tbl'>

        <div class='thead'>

            <div class='th'>

            <?php

                for($i=0; $i<mysql_num_fields($query);$i++) 
                echo "<div class='td'>".mysql_field_name($query,$i)."</div>";

            ?>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class='tbody'>

        <?php
        while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))     {
            /* If two or more columns of the result have the same field names, the last column will take precedence. */
            echo "<div class='tr'>";
            for($i=0; $i<mysql_num_fields($query);$i++) echo "<div class='td'>".$res[mysql_field_name($query,$i)]."</div>\n";
            echo "</div>\n";    
        }
        ?>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>

<?php include("close.inc.php");
```

Thank you and kudos for the guy who can provide an explanation for this mess.

Comment: Why are you using div's for tabular data? That's what tables are for.

Comment: not quite, i want vertical tbody and horizontal scroling of thead and tbody, the reason why i want to go DIY is because existing plugins don't work for what i'm trying to build...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up doing this

```
    <script>

    $(function () {
        $(".edt").click(function (event) {
            $(this).editable('ajax_save.php?table=date_vpn',{
                id      : 'id',
                name        : $(this).attr('col'),
                submit      : 'Save',
                cancel      : 'Cancel',
                tooltip     : ''
            });
        });
    });     


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".tblh_wrap").scroll(function () { 
                $(".tblb_wrap").scrollLeft($(".tblh_wrap").scrollLeft());
        });
        $(".tblb_wrap").scroll(function () { 
                $(".tblh_wrap").scrollLeft($(".tblb_wrap").scrollLeft());
        });
    });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

<?php

    $syntax = 'your usual mysql query';

    $query  = mysql_query($syntax) or die(mysql_error());
    $cols   = mysql_num_fields($query);
    $td_w   = 150;  $tr_w = $cols*$td_w;    /* td_width default 150px :) */

?>

<style type='text/css'>

    table   {

        width           :100%;
        table-layout    :fixed;

    }

    tr      {

        width           :<?=$tr_w."px"?>

    }

    td      {

        width           :<?=$td_w."px"?>;
        overflow        :hidden;
        white-space     :nowrap;

    }

    .tblh_wrap  {

        width           :1000px;
        overflow        :hidden;

    }

    .tblb_wrap  {

        height          :500px;
        width           :1000px;
        overflow        :auto;

    }       

</style>

<div class='tblh_wrap'>

<table>

        <tr>
        <?php

            for($i=0; $i<mysql_num_fields($query);$i++) 
            echo "<td>".mysql_field_name($query,$i)."</td>";

        ?>
        </tr>

</table>

</div>

<div class='tblb_wrap'>

<table>

        <?php

        while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))     {
            /* If two or more columns of the result have the same field names, the last column will take precedence. */
            echo "<tr>";
            for($i=0; $i<mysql_num_fields($query);$i++) echo "<td class='edt' id='' col=''>".$res[mysql_field_name($query,$i)]."</td>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n"; 
        }

        ?>

</table>

</div>
```

My solution works because it is a table with fixed header, scrollable horizontally and tbody content that synchronizes with header horizontally and has vertical scrolling features, done with jquery, regular html and php

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use divs in order to get scrollable body you can just do this way

**CSS**

```
table tbody { overflow: scroll; height: 200px; }
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
   <thead>
      .... your head items
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     ... your body items
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This wont work on older browsers so be careful.

Comment: ok... but your solution doesn't provide horizontal scrolling , the table will overflow if you have no wrapper div, i want to implement tbody vertical scrolling and in case i scroll tbody content horizontally, thead should keep up with it, read my source again pls

Comment: put table into div and make it scrollable then you will have vertical with the tbody and horizontal within div.